# Conditional split satisfying both the conditions

Tags: sql, ssis

I have sql execute task where it has query like `select count(*) from table1`, and I am passing the count value to a variable say X. Then I add a data flow task where it has a ole DB source with `select * from table1`. Then I add a conditional split where the condition is `@[User::X] > 0 and @[User::X] == 0`. If the count is 0 create a empty file or else create a file with table data.

But here when I execute the package, both empty file and the file with data is getting created.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: A couple things to check: 1) make sure in your logic that the execution paths are completely separate (i.e. if the `>0` condition is triggered, in no way can the `==0` condition also be triggered and vice-versa.  One way to do this is with `if-then-else` logic, 2) this one is a stretch, but maybe there is some issue when your `SELECT COUNT(*)` returns `NULL`?

Comment: A data flow conditional split is not an exclusive if-else.   it creates multiple paths, the secondary paths will still execute with 0 rows if the data doesn't match the condition.   What you are looking for is a [precedence constraint](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/11-Implement-If-condition-in-SSIS-package.html) in the control flow.